# How to save excel file without sql data source

Tags: excel-2010

I have a spread sheet which has 5 tabs, each tab updates from a SQL data source (not as a pivot table though), is there a way in excel (2010) that gives me the option to save a copy of just the data and not the connection properties ect. Basically the file is 6mb and i need to get it down.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it does not seem like you have tried anything I have two suggestions:

It could be as simple as:

Grouping Sheets and copying them to a new workbook.

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Copy
...
```

Or even:

```
Range("A1:E20").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                       :=False, Transpose:=False
```

You have to give those a try and let us know of the output, so then we can adjust those and find a solution that suits you!

Comment: the end user decided they wanted to do as little as possible, so I've told them once they refresh the data to do a file save as and zip the file for sending! The grouping and saving/copying would have been the route to take! Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

I save the workbook with the connections to a new workbook. Go into the new workbook and remove the data connections.